# Создание объекта класса

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно создать объект класса с именем введённым с клавиатуры.

```
char* obj_name = new char [64];
cin >> obj_name;
Classname obj_name;
```

Как это выполнить? Спасибо.

Comment: @dizar47, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Это касается всех ваших вопросов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++ такое невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается через один большой if/case (в зависимости от кол-ва и ситуации). То есть, в общем виде это будет выглядеть как

```
class Text : public TBaseClass {};
class Word : public TBaseClass {};
TBaseClass n;
if (obj_name == "Text") {
    n = new Text();
} else if (obj_name == "Word") {
    n = new Word();
} else {
    n = NULL;
    cout << "unknown object name";
}
```

Когда классов будет больше 3-5, все это дело заворачивают в map, ключ - имя, значение - функция/метод, которая может создать класс.

Comment: Я так понял, что автор имеет ввиду создание экземпляра объекта с произвольным именем - любым.

Comment: С произвольным именем не получиться. У класса может не быть конструктора по умолчанию.
Но главное препятствие в том, что в с++ классы не имеют общего предка. Поэтому, класс то создать можно, но что с ним потом делать...

Comment: В любом случае это бессмыслица. Все эти имена (классов, переменных, пр.) исчезают на этапе компиляции. Варианты с внешними штуками типа CORBA, COM и т.д. -- разговор отдельный. А на стадии выполнения имён уже нет (могут быть в RTTI, но их значение не обязано быть читабельным)

Comment: Могут исчезать, но компилятор не обязан так делать. Он может и сохранить.

Comment: И даже обязан. Если требуется информация для отладчика.

Comment: изобретаем массивы?:)

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь попробовать сделать это например используя контейнер Map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class CustomClass{
public:
    //...
    void test(){
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    map<string, CustomClass*> classes;

    string className;
    cin >> className;

    CustomClass *one = new CustomClass();
    classes.insert(make_pair<string, CustomClass>(className, one));

    classes[className]->test();
    // или classes["ручками пишем"]->test();

    return 0;
}
```

Но у данного метода есть проблемы, если много классов вставить в контейнер то понадобится время для их поиска, хотя это может быть не критично.

Если вам нужно обращаться так к классам разного типа, то придется создавать отдельно контейнеры, например:

```
map<string, int> iMap;
map<string, MyClass*> myMap;
map<string, TwoClass*> tClass;
```

и позже производить поиск нужного элемента в каждом из них.

Чтобы не создавать кучу контейнеров под каждый класс, можно создать базовый класс для всех ваших классов которые вы хотите так использовать, а в контейнере хранить указатель на базовый класс, например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class MyBase {
//..
};

class Player : public MyBase {
//..
};

class Home : public MyBase {
//..
};

int main(){
    map<string, MyBase*> classes;

    string className;
    cin >> className;

    Player *player = new Player();
    classes.insert(make_pair<string, MyBase*>(className, player));

    cin >> className;
    Home *home = new Home();
    classes.insert(make_pair<string, MyBase*>(className, home));

    Player* myPlayer = dynamic_cast<Player*>(classes[className]);

    return 0;
}
```

Ну а чтобы позже получить нужный вам класс из базового можно использовать dynamic_cast.
Но вам необходимо будет точно знать какой класс скрывается за данным именем, чтобы преобразовать указатель на базовый класс в нужный нам класс.

И вот подкину еще костыльный вариант, это в базовом классе создать enum с типами всех ваших классов и переменную хранящую этот enum, приведу готовый говнокод:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class MyBase {
public:
    MyBase(){
        classType = ClassType::MyBase;
    }

    enum class ClassType {
        MyBase = 0,
        Player,
        Home
        // и т.д. если у вас есть еще наследники данного класса MyBase
    }

    ClassType getType() const {
        return classType;
    }

protected:
    ClassType classType;
};

class Player : public MyBase {
public:
    Player(){
        classType = ClassType::Player;
    }
//..
};

class Home : public MyBase {
public:
    Home(){
        classType = ClassType::Home;
    }
//..
};

int main(){
    map<string, MyBase*> classes;

    string className;
    cin >> className;

    Player *player = new Player();
    classes.insert(make_pair<string, MyBase*>(className, player));

    cin >> className;
    Home *home = new Home();
    classes.insert(make_pair<string, MyBase*>(className, home));

    MyBase* ptr = classes[className];
    Player* playerPtr = nullptr;
    auto type = ptr->getType();
    if (type == MyBase::ClassType::Home){
        playerPtr = dynamic_cast<Player*>(ptr); // Получили указатель на объект нужного типа
    }

    return 0;
}
```